# Generate textbox in gridview on button click? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` in which `textbox` is generated dynamically on `RowDataBound` event.I want to generate 3 more `textbox` below `gridview` on `button` click.
Here is my gridview[image: LINK]

Here is my code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
string s = Session["num"].ToString();
int num = Int32.Parse(s);
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
for (int i = 0; i <num; i++)
{
 TextBox txt = new TextBox();
 txt.Height = 25;
 txt.Width = 150;
 txt.Font.Size = 10;
 txt.ID = "txt" + i;
 txt.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
 e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(txt);
}
}
}
```

Comment: So where is your question or problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your exact problem is, but this [**Link**](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Adding-Dynamic-Rows-in-ASP.Net-GridView-Control-with-TextBoxes.aspx) might help you. Anyway, you can simply generate `TextBox` dynamically using `Button Click` Event.

The example shown below generates three `TextBox` Control on a Click Event:

```
TextBox txt;
static int i = 0;
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(i%2==0)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            txt= new TextBox();
            txt.Height = 25;
            txt.Width = 150;
            txt.Font.Size = 10;
            txt.ID = j.ToString();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txt);
         }
     }
     i++;                                           
}
```

*Note:* When you **dynamically** add controls to an ASP.NET page at **runtime** the object references are lost at **postback** because they have no **object reference variable** in the codebehind.

Comment: I want to add `textboxes` dynamically in `gridview` is it work for `gridview`?add more 3 `textbox` blow these `textboxes` in gridview when i click button,then when i again click button then again 3 `textbox` generated

Comment: I don't need to generate `textbox` in page.I need to generate `textbox` in gridview